# I want to calculate monthly payments for a mortgage

Tags: python

```
def mortgage_calculator():
    annual_int_rate = 0
    annual_int_rate = float(annual_int_rate)
    mortgage_life = 0
    mortgage_life = float(mortgage_life)
    mortgage_amount = float(raw_input("Enter the amount would you like to borrow: "))

    salary = float(raw_input("Enter your salary per annum: "))

    if salary > 15000 and salary <= 24999 and mortgage_amount > 50000:
        annual_int_rate += 0.15
        mortgage_life += 30
    elif salary > 24999 and salary <= 44999 and mortgage_amount > 50000:
        annual_int_rate += 0.125
        mortgage_life += 25
    elif salary > 45000 and salary <= 64999 and mortgage_amount > 50000:
        annual_int_rate += 0.10
        mortgage_life += 20
    else:
        annual_int_rate += 0.06
        mortgage_life += 15

    r = float(annual_int_rate/12)
    n = mortgage_life * 12
    mnth_paym = mortgage_amount * (r(1 + r)**n/(1 + r)**n - 1)
    print("Monthly payments for the next {} months will be {}".format(n, mnth_paym))

def run():
    employment_check = raw_input("Are you employed [y/n]: ").upper()
    if employment_check == "Y":
        mortgage_calculator()
    else:
        print("You don't qualify for a mortgage")

run()
```

I want to calculate monthly payments for a mortgage using the formula(mnth_paym) at the bottom of the mortgage_calculator method but I'm getting an TypeError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the below line of your code, an operator is missing after the first use of variable `r`

```
mnth_paym = mortgage_amount * (r(1 + r)**n/(1 + r)**n - 1)
```

Do you mean `r * (1 + r) ...` ?

Comment: Yh I did..I forgot the * operator. Thank you. My programme now runs.